# Is there any python method acts same with matlab's scatteredInterpolant?

Tags: python, matlab

## this is my matlab code

```
data = xlsread('data3.xlsx');
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);
z = data(:,3); 

%% Interpolation function

F = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,z,'natural')
```

Is there any method to work same with this matlab code in Python IDE?

Comment: Several pages suggest the use of `scipy.interpolate.griddata`.  https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12057/how-to-interpolate-scattered-data-to-a-regular-grid-in-python

Comment: actually  I don't know about how to change the input values for griddata. How should I change the dataFrame x, y, z in for python form?